# How to fetch/get recently created channel in disccord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am making a bot that does a command that does LTM!create . What it is supposed to do is create a channel which it does. Then after the time that is set in the command, it is supposed to turn to a private channel. I got everything to work but I don't know how to get the channel that was just created. Here is the command for it

````
        const name = message.content.replace('LTM!create ', '')


        message.guild.channels
            .create(name, {
                type: 'text',
            })
            .then((channel) => {
                const categoryId = '850420491915493387'
                channel.setParent(categoryId)
            })


        console.log(message.author)
        const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('LTM created!')
            .setFooter('created by' + " " + message.author.username)
            .setColor('#FFD700')

        message.channel.send(Embed)


        setTimeout(() => {
            const private_channel = client.channels.cache.get("CHANNEL_ID");
            private_channel.updateOverwrite(message.guild.id, {
                SEND_MESSAGES: false
            })


        }, 10000)
    })```
````

Answer (score 1):

[`message.guild.channels.create()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create) resolves with a channel. You can use `async`/`await` or put your code inside your `.then()` call to access this channel.

**`await`/`async`**

```js
const newChannel = await message.guild.channels.create(name, {type: "text"});
newChannel.updateOverwrite(message.guild.id, {
  SEND_MESSAGES: false
});
```

**`.then()`**

```js
message.guild.channels.create(name, {type: "text"}).then((newChannel) => {
  newChannel.updateOverwrite(message.guild.id, {
    SEND_MESSAGES: false
  });
});
```

Comment: this is what I did pastebin.com/LFySR2us. But I got the error Cannot read property 'updateOverwrite' of undefined @theusaf

Comment: Hmm. I don't really know why it's doing that. I just tried that exact code, and it worked as expected.

Comment: maybe you cant use it in a setTimeout?

Comment: Could be. It doesn't make sense to me, but try taking it out of the setTimeout and see if it still creates that error.

Comment: so I tried it without and nothing happened and then I tried this https://pastebin.com/Phq1WvzF and I didnt get a error but it looked like nothing happened @theusaf